# Problems creating HDInsight + Datalake cluster using azure cli and templates

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-cli, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create a HDInsight Spark cluster. I also have a Datalake storage which I want to use in the HDInsight cluster. I have generated a certificate to connect the HDInsight with Datalake. I've done it in the web portal and downloaded the templates and certificate. Now I am using Azure CLI to create the cluster and delete it when needed automatically.

**deploy.sh** (I've just added verbose and debug options to the last command)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# -e: immediately exit if any command has a non-zero exit status
# -o: prevents errors in a pipeline from being masked
# IFS new value is less likely to cause confusing bugs when looping arrays or arguments (e.g. $@)

usage() { echo "Usage: $0 -i <subscriptionId> -g <resourceGroupName> -n <deploymentName> -l <resourceGroupLocation>" 1>&2; exit 1; }

declare subscriptionId=""
declare resourceGroupName=""
declare deploymentName=""
declare resourceGroupLocation=""

# Initialize parameters specified from command line
while getopts ":i:g:n:l:" arg; do
 case "${arg}" in
      i)
        subscriptionId=${OPTARG}
        ;;
      g)
        resourceGroupName=${OPTARG}
        ;;
      n)
        deploymentName=${OPTARG}
        ;;
      l)
        resourceGroupLocation=${OPTARG}
        ;;
      esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

#Prompt for parameters is some required parameters are missing
if [[ -z "$subscriptionId" ]]; then
 echo "Your subscription ID can be looked up with the CLI using: az account show --out json "
 echo "Enter your subscription ID:"
 read subscriptionId
 [[ "${subscriptionId:?}" ]]
fi

if [[ -z "$resourceGroupName" ]]; then
 echo "This script will look for an existing resource group, otherwise a new one will be created "
 echo "You can create new resource groups with the CLI using: az group create "
 echo "Enter a resource group name"
 read resourceGroupName
 [[ "${resourceGroupName:?}" ]]
fi

if [[ -z "$deploymentName" ]]; then
 echo "Enter a name for this deployment:"
 read deploymentName
fi

if [[ -z "$resourceGroupLocation" ]]; then
 echo "If creating a *new* resource group, you need to set a location "
 echo "You can lookup locations with the CLI using: az account list-locations "

 echo "Enter resource group location:"
 read resourceGroupLocation
fi

#templateFile Path - template file to be used
templateFilePath="template.json"

if [ ! -f "$templateFilePath" ]; then
 echo "$templateFilePath not found"
 exit 1
fi

#parameter file path
parametersFilePath="parameters.json"

if [ ! -f "$parametersFilePath" ]; then
 echo "$parametersFilePath not found"
 exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$subscriptionId" ] || [ -z "$resourceGroupName" ] || [ -z "$deploymentName" ]; then
 echo "Either one of subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, deploymentName is empty"
 usage
fi

#login to azure using your credentials
az account show 1> /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ];
then
 az login
fi

#set the default subscription id
az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

set +e

#Check for existing RG
az group show --name $resourceGroupName 1> /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
 echo "Resource group with name" $resourceGroupName "could not be found. Creating new resource group.."
 set -e
 (
      set -x
      az group create --name $resourceGroupName --location $resourceGroupLocation 1> /dev/null
 )
 else
 echo "Using existing resource group..."
fi

#Start deployment
echo "Starting deployment..."
(
 set -x
 az group deployment create --name "$deploymentName" --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" --template-file "$templateFilePath" --parameters "@${parametersFilePath}" --verbose --debug
)

if [ $?  == 0 ];
 then
 echo "Template has been successfully deployed"
fi
```

**template.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "0.9.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "clusterName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the HDInsight cluster to create."
            }
        },
        "clusterLoginUserName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "admin",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "These credentials can be used to submit jobs to the cluster and to log into cluster dashboards."
            }
        },
        "clusterLoginPassword": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The password must be at least 10 characters in length and must contain at least one digit, one non-alphanumeric character, and one upper or lower case letter."
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "westeurope",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location where all azure resources will be deployed."
            }
        },
        "clusterVersion": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "3.6",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "HDInsight cluster version."
            }
        },
        "clusterWorkerNodeCount": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 4,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The number of nodes in the HDInsight cluster."
            }
        },
        "clusterKind": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "SPARK",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The type of the HDInsight cluster to create."
            }
        },
        "sshUserName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "sshuser",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "These credentials can be used to remotely access the cluster."
            }
        },
        "sshPassword": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The password must be at least 10 characters in length and must contain at least one digit, one non-alphanumeric character, and one upper or lower case letter."
            }
        },
        "identityCertificate": {
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "identityCertificatePassword": {
            "type": "securestring"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-03-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('clusterName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "properties": {
                "clusterVersion": "[parameters('clusterVersion')]",
                "osType": "Linux",
                "tier": "standard",
                "clusterDefinition": {
                    "kind": "[parameters('clusterKind')]",
                    "componentVersion": {
                        "Spark": "2.3"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "gateway": {
                            "restAuthCredential.isEnabled": true,
                            "restAuthCredential.username": "[parameters('clusterLoginUserName')]",
                            "restAuthCredential.password": "[parameters('clusterLoginPassword')]"
                        },
                        "core-site": {
                            "fs.defaultFS": "adl://home",
                            "dfs.adls.home.hostname": "vivienda.azuredatalakestore.net",
                            "dfs.adls.home.mountpoint": "/clusters/vivienda/"
                        },
                        "clusterIdentity": {
                            "clusterIdentity.applicationId": "5e6237dc-897d-4a94-9913-e25a987d00bc",
                            "clusterIdentity.certificate": "[parameters('identityCertificate')]",
                            "clusterIdentity.aadTenantId": "https://login.windows.net/c1c86fed-0aa0-465e-92be-5b97e2b584f9",
                            "clusterIdentity.resourceUri": "https://datalake.azure.net/",
                            "clusterIdentity.certificatePassword": "[parameters('identityCertificatePassword')]"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "storageaccounts": []
                },
                "computeProfile": {
                    "roles": [
                        {
                            "autoScale": null,
                            "name": "headnode",
                            "minInstanceCount": 1,
                            "targetInstanceCount": 2,
                            "hardwareProfile": {
                                "vmSize": "Standard_D12_V2"
                            },
                            "osProfile": {
                                "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                                    "username": "[parameters('sshUserName')]",
                                    "password": "[parameters('sshPassword')]"
                                }
                            },
                            "virtualNetworkProfile": null,
                            "scriptActions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "autoScale": null,
                            "name": "workernode",
                            "targetInstanceCount": 4,
                            "hardwareProfile": {
                                "vmSize": "Standard_D13_V2"
                            },
                            "osProfile": {
                                "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                                    "username": "[parameters('sshUserName')]",
                                    "password": "[parameters('sshPassword')]"
                                }
                            },
                            "virtualNetworkProfile": null,
                            "scriptActions": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**parameters.json** (I think my problems come with this file)

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "clusterName": {
            "value": "cname"
        },
        "clusterLoginUserName": {
            "value": "admin"
        },
        "clusterLoginPassword": {
            "value": null
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "westeurope"
        },
        "clusterWorkerNodeCount": {
            "value": 4
        },
        "clusterKind": {
            "value": "SPARK"
        },
        "clusterVersion": {
            "value": "3.6"
        },
        "sshUserName": {
            "value": "sshuser"
        },
        "sshPassword": {
            "value": null
        },
        "identityCertificate": {
            "value": null
        },
        "identityCertificatePassword": {
            "value": null
        }
    }
}
```

In the parameter.json is needed to fill "**clusterLoginPassword**", "**sshPassword**", "**identityCertificate**" and "**identityCertificatePassword**". I've tried to fill this fields in different ways but I get errors with all of them.

1. 3 password fields with the string value "XXXXX", and identityCertificate with the path of the certificate file "cert-download.pfx".

**Result:**

```
"code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "User input validation failed. Errors: The request payload is invalid. The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. "
```

2. Convert passwords to base 64

**Result:**

```
"code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "User input validation failed. Errors: The request payload is invalid. The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. "
```

3. As I saw in the template file that all those files where of type **securestring**, using the following powershell code I got the content of the certificate in base64:

```
    PS /tmp/azure> $certPassword = "XXXXXXXX"
    PS /tmp/azure> $certFilePath = "cert-download.pfx"
    PS /tmp/azure> $certPasswordSecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $certPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    
    PS /tmp/azure> $certificatePFX = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certFilePath, $certPasswordSecureString)
    PS /tmp/azure> $credential = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certificatePFX.GetRawCertData())
    PS /tmp/azure> $credential
    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
```

I put that result in the parameters file.

**Result**:

```
"code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "DeploymentDocument 'AmbariConfiguration_1_7' failed the validation. Error: 'Service Principal Details are invalid - The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate.',DeploymentDocument 'AmbariConfiguration_1_7' failed the validation. Error: 'Error while getting access to the datalake storage account vivienda: The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate..'"
```

I've also read about **Key vault**, but I have not seen how to use it from the parameters.json file.

So I need help filling the parameters.json in the correct way :)

Comment: have you had your issue resolved?